# Wireless controller for OpenWRT access points

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, openwrt

I have around 30 OpenWRT access points in our building (plenty of them are old Linksys). It's time to update wireless network. Some of old APs will be replaced with TP Link Archos Ac1750. Problem is that maintain 30+ access points is quite quite time consuming (if you want to change passwords, you have to do this on each access point). Solution is to use wireless controller. And here is my question. Which one do you suggest me? I found only OpenWISP, but the documentation is rather poor.

Thanks

Comment: Try Ubiquiti hardware. It comes with management software. Really, though, recommendation questions are **NOT** allowed on SuperUser.

Answer (score 2):

If you still hadn't found the answer - use [OpenWISP](http://openwisp.org) - open-source, free multiple wi-fi AP's network management, based on OpenWRT, though it is not a point-and-click solution - it requires you to add the [openwisp-config](https://github.com/openwisp/openwisp-config/) package, but as far as you're using so many OpenWRT's so long I assume you are not afraid of that.